# In dartlang, what are the differences between dill and kernel snapshot?

Tags: dart

Considering -
The file encoding, 
The file size, 
Inner data structure,
Startup time and etc.

And what is the main reason to choose dill file to start dart application?
Which one has better startup time performance? And why?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, [please see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

https://mrale.ph/dartvm/ is a great summary from a long-time Dart language team member.

As I understand it dill files and kernel snapshot are the same thing. `dill` is just the name for the file extension used for Kernel (AoT snapshots)

> Since Dart 2 VM no longer has the ability to directly execute Dart from raw source, instead VM expects to be given Kernel binaries (also called dill files) which contain serialized Kernel ASTs. snapshot

I assume what you actually want to know is the difference between AoT and JiT snapshots.

> Initially snapshots did not include machine code, however this
> capability was later added when AOT compiler was developed. Motivation
> for developing AOT compiler and snapshots-with-code was to allow VM to
> be used on the platforms where JITing is impossible due to platform
> level restrictions.
>
> Snapshots-with-code work almost in the same way as normal snapshots
> with a minor difference: they include a code section which unlike the
> rest of the snapshot does not require deserialization. This code
> section laid in way that allows it to directly become part of the heap
> after it was mapped into memory.

Startup time

> AppJIT snapshots were introduced to reduce JIT warm up time for large Dart applications like dartanalyzer or  dart2js. When these tools are used on small projects they spent as much time doing actual work as VM spends JIT compiling these apps.

So the main reason to use AOT is that JIT is not allowed (mainly iOS)
or for short-lived commands where continual optimization based on code usage (hot-spot) would unlikely lead to any results.

For a discussion about the size see also https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28655#issuecomment-428370886

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is important to understand the differences and there are ways to generate kernel file by snapshot-kind or gen_kernel or frontend service. Now I found by indicating snapshot-kind = 'kernel'  could take sometimes long time to finish compiling (In my case over 5 sec approx.).  If the a kernel snapshot is equivalent to a dill in terms of performance or volumn , maybe we could be able to use kernel service to customize to address issue.

Answer (score 0):

### Since you are wondering about size, startup time, etc.

- For fastest launch + small size (but not portable): use **AOT snapshot**
- For portability (includes dart runtime) + fast launch (but large): use **Self-contained executables (exe)**
- For portability (excludes dart runtime) + smallest size (but slow): use **Portable snapshots (kernel)**

---

### Size

I took a [random dart program](https://github.com/jeanluc243/dart-calculator/blob/master/calc.dart) from the internet (a seemingly non functioning dart program, upgraded it to Dart 2.12/ sound null safety), and built all the outputs:

- Original files (main.dart, calc.dart) 74B and 3.0K
- exe (Self-contained executables) 4.9M
- main.aot (AOT snapshot) 1.0M
- main.dill (Kernel snapshot) 6.8K
- The jit one didn't output any files, it just ran the program, even when I ran `dart compile jit-snapshot main.dart -o calc.jit`

### Startup time

The start up time is documented at [dart compile](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile).

> Although kernel snapshots have reduced startup time compared to Dart code, they can have much slower startup than architecture-specific AOT output formats.

---

## Answering the title

`.dill` is the extension for portable snapshots (kernel). From [Dart Compile docs](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile#kernel):

> Use the kernel subcommand to package up an app into a single, portable
> file that can be run on all operating systems and CPU architectures. A
> kernel snapshot contains a binary form of the abstract syntax tree
> (Kernel AST) for a Dart program.
>
> Here’s an example of creating and running a kernel snapshot:

```sh
$ dart compile kernel bin/myapp.dart
Compiling bin/myapp.dart to kernel file bin/myapp.dill.
$ dart run bin/myapp.dill
```